# How can I embed HTML content with specific widgets in react/js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, widget

We are working on a large social network site built with a micro frontend architecture in React and utilize some private libraries. Our goal is to enhance user engagement by allowing users to embed HTML content, similar to Twitter, and include specific widgets (e.g., comments with details like the number of likes).

I'm seeking guidance or examples on how to kickstart the implementation of this functionality. Any references or advice on how to approach this within our tech stack would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!